# How to carry id at CustomPageAdapter?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-pageradapter

I have `List<Item> mItems`

In Gridview activity provides {id},

`i.putExtra("id", item.getDrawableId());`

In Fullscreen activity, I use `viewpager` with `CustomPageAdapter extends PagerAdapter`. Like this;

```
int id = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("id");
ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
CustomPageAdapter mCustomPagerAdapter = new CustomPageAdapter(Fullscreen.this, id);
viewPager.setAdapter(mCustomPagerAdapter);
```

In CustomPageAdapter,

```
public class CustomPageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    Context context;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    int id;

    public CustomPageAdapter(Context context, int id) {
        this.context = context;
        this.layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(this.context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.id = id; // id ?
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return id; // ?
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((View) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        View view = this.layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.pager_list_items, container, false);
     //   SubsamplingScaleImageView imageView = (SubsamplingScaleImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
     //   imageView.setImage(ImageSource.resource( // here is id));
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((View) object);
    }
}
```

Comment: Pass id using Adaptor constuctor

Comment: in getCount() method you have to specify no.of pages u want.

Comment: I need to loop, to show all Images at getCount(). It doesn't happen even I carry id. Something wrong?